# three20 TTTableViewController -> UINavigationBar Color/Style Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, uinavigationbar

i am using the [three20](http://three20.info) `TTTableViewController` for my current project. For switching between views, i use `UITabBar`. A few of my views have subviews - i don't use `TTNavigator` for switching between those views, but my own logic (simple push/pop viewControllers).

Somehow, i am not able to set the color/style of my `UINavigationBar` in those subviews (initially, it works for my mainviews that are controlled by the `tabbarcontroller`).

My setup looks like this:

In my `AppDelegate` i prepare the `rootViewController` and the `navigationController`

```
RootViewController *rootController = [[[RootViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
navigationController_ = [[UINavigationController alloc]    initWithRootViewController:rootController];
navigationController_.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;              
window_ = [[PSWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
window_.rootViewController = navigationController_;
```

Here i set `UIBarStyleBlack` as my default style. When i run the app, and check out the different views, the navigationbar color/style is correct.

One of my `mainViews` forwards the user to a `TTTableView`

```
UIViewController* targetViewController = [[[NSClassFromString(targetVC) alloc] init] autorelease];             
if(targetViewController != nil) {   
     [[self retain] autorelease];           
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];   
     targetViewController.title = @"A Title";   
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];   
}
```

The code above pops the current viewController and pushes the `targetViewController` onto the stack. This works. However, the `navigationBar` color/style is now the default one, and not black, as i set it in my `AppDelegate`. I have checked the object addresses in the debugger and it is the same `navigationController` + `navigationBar` as the one in my `rootViewController`.

When I explicitly set the `navigationBar` color/style in the targets initializer function, the settings are ignored.

Additionally, when i now hit the back-button in the navigationbar, the barstyle/color in my `mainViews` is also incorrect (from black to default).

Any ideas how I could debug/fix this?

Comment: Hi, yes somehow i did but i am sure its not the correct way to do it. I think the reason for my problem was that i did use some three20 components together with my own navigation controller (instead of using ttnavigator + mapping). I have the feeling that the navigationcontroller got messed up somehow. What i do now is to set the navigationbar color/title explicitly in the viewWillAppear() function of my view controller: `self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor]; self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"My Title";`

Comment: Thanks, using viewWillAppear() solved it :)